# Adding components dynamically in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel which takes up the majority of the screen space, it's called contentPane. Inside this is another JPanel called canvas. I want to add another JPanel to contentPane during runtime which will act as a kind of floating dialog, so I need it to be on the very top layer some how.

The event to add this dialog is originally fired from a MouseDown event in canvas. My code so far doesn't seem to work. Nothing appears at all:

```
JPanel editor = new JPanel();
editor.setLocation(500, 100);
editor.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
app.contentPane.add(editor);
app.validate();
```

Comment: The layout manager is probably using the components preferred size, with is, by default, 0x0

Comment: To get help sooner, provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I need it to be on the very top layer some how.

You can't just add components on top of one another. Swing layouts work in 2 dimensions.

See [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) or [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) or maybe a [Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).